# Can't execute gradlew task using AndroidStudio and Ubuntu - can't create service of type ScriptPluginFactory

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, gradle, android-studio-3.0

Basically, what the question says. Any task I execute inside AndroidStudio's terminal window using ./gradlew gives me this exception.

I read in some places that this issue could be because of a permission problem, but I already gave all the folders inside my project the chmod 777 permission, so it couldn't be that.

Also, building and running clean directly from AndroidStudio works just fine. The problem is when I run it using the terminal.

Versions:
AndroidStudio 3.2.1

Gradle 4.7

This is the stacktrace:

```
19:35:23.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
19:35:23.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
19:35:23.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
19:35:23.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
19:35:23.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().
19:35:23.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
19:35:23.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
19:35:23.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
19:35:23.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
19:35:23.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
19:35:23.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
19:35:23.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:816)
19:35:23.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:767)
19:35:23.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
19:35:23.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:284)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:279)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:179)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:108)
19:35:23.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:61)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
19:35:23.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
19:35:23.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:816)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:767)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:284)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:279)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:301)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:293)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
19:35:23.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:814)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 61 more
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not generate a proxy class for class org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:228)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:80)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.plugin.internal.PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry$BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy(PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry.java:106)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:814)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 79 more
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class;
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.define(ClassLoaderUtils.java:104)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.model.internal.asm.AsmClassGenerator.define(AsmClassGenerator.java:58)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.model.internal.asm.AsmClassGenerator.define(AsmClassGenerator.java:54)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassBuilderImpl.generate(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:967)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:226)
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 88 more
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
19:35:23.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
19:35:23.810 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem solved by downgrading the JDK version to 8. I think you can switch it by setting JAVA_HOME environment variable.